Does CosmosDB throttle write requests for multi-region account using Session Consistency when read region lags behind?
In Cosmosdb's documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/consistency-levels#bounded-staleness-consistency it says that:

Bounded Staleness is beneficial primarily to single-region write accounts with two or more regions. If the data lag in a region (determined per physical partition) exceeds the configured staleness value, writes for that partition are throttled until staleness is back within the configured upper bound.

And in the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/reliability/reliability-cosmos-db-nosql?toc=%2Fazure%2Fcosmos-db%2Ftoc.json#durability it says the RPO of Bounded staleness is determined by K and T where as for session consistency it is Less than 15 minutes.
For an account with session consistency configured, with one read region and one write region, if the read region goes through region outage and lags behind by more than 15 minutes, would write region also throttle write requests? And what happens in the case where there are two write regions?

can you add what you have tried and error if you are facing any error?

I'm sure that it won't throttle writes in this case for "Session, consistent prefix, eventual" as these are prioritising availability over consistency.

@PratikLad, I am still in the design phase and curious about the behavior of these different consistency levels during a region outage. I am trying to compare the difference between session consistency and bounded staleness consistency with very high K and T for a multi-region account when one region faces outage.
